# Daily interest calculator that's supposed to credit monthly given various user inputs

Tags: date, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm new to programming and have been working on something to learn Python for the last few days.  I'm trying to create a program that calculates daily interest and credits interest monthly given user generated inputs.

The good: The program can add deposits to the initial balance every 14 days as I wanted.  The program is able to determine whether an input is a leap year or not.  The program is able to determine the daily interest.

The bad: I haven't been able to figure out how to get the program to sum the calculated daily interests for a given month then add it to the beginning balance of the next month.

```python
import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import calendar
from decimal import Decimal
def gupta():
    print("Enter a start date in YYYY-MM-DD format")
    date_entry = input() #records account's start date as string
    year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-')) #splits contents of date_entry string variable into separate integers thus rendering date1 variable actionable by datetime.date
    date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day) #records account's start date as datetime.date (module?)
    print("Enter an end date in YYYY-MM-DD format") 
    date_entry = input() #records account's end date as string
    year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-')) #splits contents of date_entry string variable into separate integers thus rendering date1 variable actionable by datetime.date
    date2 = datetime.date(year, month, day) #records account's end date as datetime.date (module?)
    print("The starting date is " + str(date1) + " and the ending date is " + str(date2))
    print("Enter your initial balance")
    initial_balance = Decimal(input()) #requests initial balance (assumes this is amount to be deposited every 14 days)
    print("Enter your interest rate (as a decimal)")
    interest_rate = Decimal(input()) #records interest rate as a decimal
    date1 = date1.toordinal() #changes date1 to ordinal
    date2 = date2.toordinal() #changes date2 to ordinal
    list_interest = []
    for current_date in range(date1, date2 + 1): #cycles through date1 and date2 using a step/iteration of 1
        date_spread = current_date - date1
        new = current_date + 1
        print(date.fromordinal(current_date).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        print(list_interest)
        if date_spread != 14: #checks to see whether additional deposit is going to be made
            current_date = date.fromordinal(current_date)
            new = date.fromordinal(new)
            current_date_y = str(current_date.strftime("%Y"))
            new_m = str(new.strftime("%m"))
            current_date_m = str(current_date.strftime("%m"))
            current_balance = initial_balance + 0
            print(current_balance)
            if calendar.isleap(int(current_date_y)):
                daily_interest = round(current_balance * (interest_rate / 366), 2)
                print(daily_interest)
                if current_date_m == new_m: 
                    list_interest.append(daily_interest)
                    print(list_interest)
            else:
                daily_interest = round(current_balance * (interest_rate / 365), 2)
                print(daily_interest)
                if current_date_m == new_m: 
                    list_interest.append(daily_interest)
                    print(list_interest)
            current_date = date.toordinal(current_date)
        elif date_spread == 14: #checks to see whether additional deposit is going to be made      
            current_date = date.fromordinal(current_date)
            new = date.fromordinal(new)
            current_date_y = str(current_date.strftime("%Y"))
            new_m = str(new.strftime("%m"))
            current_date_m = str(current_date.strftime("%m"))
            current_balance = initial_balance + 150
            initial_balance = current_balance
            print(current_balance)
            if calendar.isleap(int(current_date_y)):
                daily_interest = round(current_balance * (interest_rate / 366), 2)
                print(daily_interest)
                if current_date_m == new_m: 
                    list_interest.append(daily_interest)
                    print(list_interest) 
            else:
                daily_interest = round(current_balance * (interest_rate / 365), 2)
                print(daily_interest)
                if current_date_m == new_m: 
                    list_interest.append(daily_interest)
                    print(list_interest)    
            current_date = date.toordinal(current_date)
            new = date.toordinal(new)
            date1 = current_date
            list_interest = []
    #print(current_balance)
```

Comment: Could you add a simple code example illustrating your question instead of all the code? You will get much better answers if you help others to understand the problem

Comment: thanks Eriks.  i ended up figuring out what to do, but in the future i'll only add parts that are giving me problems.  someone also edited my question to make it python code, but i'm unaware of how to do that myself.